# ace() in Acepack

Tags: r, smoothing

I used to ace() function with my data to obtained smoothed transformed functions of x(s) and y. However, I did this by feeding in data (i.e. x(s) and y), leaving other arguments unchanged.

In the reference manual:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/acepack/acepack.pdf

I see a choice of weights. Is this the same as bandwidth? How do I find out what smoothing technique the authors are using behind the algo.

Appreciate some advice as I'm very new to R.

Thank you.

Comment: The way to see the algorithm is to look at the code. This is R after all, not SAS.

Comment: I see but I am not a programmer so it's difficult for me to decipher the code in front of me: